# Timestamp partitioning in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, partitioning

I am trying to create timestamp based partition in Hive. But Hive is creating data based partition. Below is my code:

```
cat test1.sh
    dat=`date +'%Y%m%d %H:%m:%S'`
    hive -f load.hql -hiveconf file_load_timestamp=$dat;

cat load.hql
INSERT OVERWRITE table perm.test partition(file_load_timestamp='${hiveconf:dat}')
SELECT a,b FROM work.temp;
```

`dt=20180102`/   =  HDFS path is getting created like this.

`dt=20180102 103455/`   =  Expecting HDFS path to be created like this.

When I tried with `%Y%m%d_%H:%m:%S`' format its working as expected. But I need space between date and timestamp.

Comment: not exactly tested, but try with format `%Y%m%d\ %H:%m:%S`. it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a folder name in HDFS with `space` in between, it is required to escape the space with `\`

```
hadoop fs -mkdir test\ 123
```

create a folder in hdfs with name `test 123`.

Similarly, hive maintains the partitions in folders created with the partition value. Thats why providing the date format `%Y%m%d\ %H%m%S` will help to create folder with spaces.
Below is tested and working:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE table person_details1 partition(datelocal='20180102\ 200128') select * from person_details;
```

`datelocal` is `String`

Edited:Executed the code, Below is working one:

```
hduser@Amit:~$ cat test1.sh 
#!/bin/sh

dat=`date +'%Y%m%d\ %H%m%S'`
hive -f load.hql -hiveconf datelocal="$dat";
hduser@Amit:~$ cat load.hql 
INSERT OVERWRITE table amit.person_details1 partition(datelocal='${hiveconf:datelocal}') select * from amit.person_details;
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response.Tried with %Y%m%d\ %H:%m:%S format in my shell script. But its giving error as below:
[nzdpmkt@ddh-dev-4-azkaban-main-001 ~]$ sh -x test1.sh
++ date '+%Y%m%d\ %H%m%S'
+ var='20180102\ 100108'
+ hive -f /home/nzdpmkt/load.hql -hiveconf 'dat=20180102\' 100108
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/opt/hadoop/apache-hive-2.1.1-bin/lib/hive-common-2.1.1.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
FAILED: ParseException line 9:0 character '<EOF>' not supported here
line 1:60 character '\' not supported here
line 9:0 character '<EOF>' not supported here

Comment: Tried executing your code, you need to add double quote while declaring the hiveconf variable`hive -f load.hql -hiveconf datelocal="$dat";`. Check double code at the end Edited my answer

Comment: you can see in your logs, `hive -f /home/nzdpmkt/load.hql -hiveconf 'dat=20180102\' 100108` the digits after `\\` were getting ignored. Double quote is required in string with spaces.

Comment: Working now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi. Directory is getting created now as expected (datelocal='20180102 200128'). But when I do select * from perm.test; its not giving any output. Could you please check from your side also

Comment: check your query if it returning result. I do not see any problem in my side. you can go to the partition folder and check if it has got data in it.

Comment: Query is not returning any result. But HDFS path is created properly with timestamp value. Also I could see part-m* files with size are available in the same path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162400/discussion-between-amit-kumar-and-user2531569).